# What is a good simpleCursorAdapter implementation from a Mediastore object?

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter, mediastore

Apologies if I am missing something very simple here, I am very new to programming.

I am trying to build a media player, and have discovered and example of the use of MediaStore.Audio to collect media for a playlist. I now need to implement an adapter to get this into a listview for the user to select. I am under the impression this is probably the most elegant way of implementing a simple track list.

So far I have:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter myAdapter;
        String[] STAR = { "*" };
        Uri allsongsuri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(allsongsuri, STAR, selection, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String song_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    int song_id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID));

                    String fullpath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));

                    String album_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
                    int album_id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));

                    String artist_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
                    int artist_id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID));
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

Now I am looking to use a simpleCursorAdaptor to listView, but not sure how to go about it, or where to put it. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to implement your own SimpleCursorAdapter like you do it with Activities.

```
MediaStoreCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter { . . .
```

To assign it to your ListView get a reference to it in OnCreate of Activity via

```
ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylistview);
```

And then assign the Adapter to it:

```
myListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

If youre a beginner you might want to look into some basic tutorials to get to know language and framework a little better before diving deeper.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for your time, I will update this thread with more detail once I have tried a few more things out based on this advice. There seems to be a few ways to go about it!